# System UUID got nulled in BIOS

Tags: windows-10, bios, windows-update, flashing, uuid

My HP laptop was working fine before I tried installing MacOS in it.

I got success in installing MacOS Big Sur where I changed the UUID in the config.plist.

But after uninstalling it (I just deleted the partition of it directly from disk management), I uninstalled my Windows too as it was detecting the motherboard as the mac one. I thought reinstalling might work.

So I reinstalled the official windows but it started creating problems with updates. It created different errors and none of the solutions to the errors worked. I reinstalled the official Windows about 6-8 times but the conclusion was the same.

[This is the error showing in the Windows Update Assistant for updating windows to 20H2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fuoa1.jpg)

Other than the windows update assistant, the default update method too wasn't allowing me to install the update leaving the notice that the update isn't ready for your device.

During the finding of the error, I entered BIOS where I found that UUID became all zero.

I reinstalled the official BIOS but it didn't help.

Can anyone please suggest me what to do? Without the UUID, Windows isn't installing updates.

I'm currently on Windows version 10.0.16299 Build 16299 (2017) [This is the official factory image which I'm currently using]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could try to update your BIOS and see if that restores the UUID.

Comment: @LPChip, I already updated BIOS but it didn't do anything. It was still zero after updating it.